# Why auto-migration doesn't create any properties in a Collection? How to make it to create them?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I have created models using `slc loopback:model` tool. Now I want Loopback to create corresponding MongoDB collections, that is to perform auto-migration.

One of the models is a `Client` model whose base class is a `User` model. That means that `client/models/client.json` is just empty because all its properties (fields) are inherited from `User`:

```
{
  "name": "Client",
  "plural": "Clients",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {},
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

So I think to myself that if I make an auto-migration, Loopback finds all `User` properties and creates `Client` collection with them. But it doesn't! My `Client` collection has only `_id` property.

Here is a my code for auto-migration:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.dataSources.mongodb.automigrate('Client', function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
};
```

My question:

Why Loopback doesn't use `User` model properties for my `Client` model? How to auto-migrate so that Loopback will create correct collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

automigrate is used to migrate model data into tables i.e. Model *name* as `tablename` and Model's *properties* as `table columns`.

Now as you are using MongoDB, it drops and creates indexes as written in [documentation](https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback-datasource-juggler/#datasource-prototype-automigrate). This is because MongoDB is schemaless.

So, probably you can avoid automigration and insert new documents directly.